# Get current path in svelte-routing

Tags: url-routing, svelte

I'm trying to access the current route in order to conditionally redirect visitor incase the current route is "/". The way I have set up right now the redirection happens at any route if you type it in the addressbar. The only candidate solution I have right now is creating a store that holds the current path and using that store to set up the condition to navigate only if the store value is "/". But I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

here is app.svelte

```
<script>
  import {Router, navigate, Route} from "svelte-routing";
  import { user, loading } from "./lib/store";
  import Authentication from "./features/authentication/Authentication.svelte";
  import Notes from "./features/notes/Notes.svelte";
  import Read from "./features/notes/components/Read.svelte";
  import Create from "./features/notes/components/Create.svelte";
  import Folders from "./features/folders/Folders.svelte";
  
  //i want to do if(!$loading && path="/") below
  $: if(!$loading) {
    if($user) navigate("/folders");
    else navigate("/authenticate");
  }
</script>
{#if $loading}
  loading..
{/if}
<Router>
{#if $user}
<Route path="/notes/read/:id" let:params>
  <Read id={params.id} />
</Route>
<Route path="/notes/create" component={Create} />
<Route path="/notes" component={Notes} />
<Route path="/folders" component={Folders} />
{:else}
  <Route path="/authenticate" component={Authentication} />
{/if}
</Router>
```

I have tried using useLocation to get the current path. unfortunately since App.svelte isn't a child of the router that doesn't work and the function is returning undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found using window.location.pathname to be the most intuitive solution in this case!

```
const path = window.location.pathname;
$: if (!$loading && path == "/") { 
  if ($user) navigate("/folders");
  else navigate("/authenticate");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.4.0, `svelte-routing` has exported the current location into the script, so all you have to do is have an export statement.

```html
<script>
  // ...
  
  //i want to do if(!$loading && path="/") below

  export let location;
  // then  here you can parse the location 
  // and find the first '/' to determine what pathname you are in.

  $: if(!$loading) {
    if($user) navigate("/folders");
    else navigate("/authenticate");
  }
</script>
```

Here is the linked issue: https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing/issues/62

Comment: The problem with solution is the same as useLocation. since App.svelte isn't a child of route it doesn't work. However I found my solution in the link you provided and I am indeed grateful!